# I am trying to connect to remote server using mysql workbench but i can't. I am using ubantu 22

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, remote-access

I'm encountering difficulties connecting to a remote MySQL server via MySQL Workbench. Despite entering the correct credentials and ensuring the server is up and running, I consistently receive connection errors. I've double-checked the host address, port number, and login credentials, but the issue persists.I've tried troubleshooting on my own but haven't been able to resolve the issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Connection details]

[image: Pop up everytime i try to connect]

[image: Error description]

Comment: The insights and suggestions are on the 2nd screenshot you embedded into your question.

Comment: Tried everything and everything is correct

Comment: In your cnf file ( check in /etc/ or in /etc/mysql/ ), find and comment (or delete) the string `bind-address=127.0.0.1` Restart the service with `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`